# How do I loop through a group of check boxes with the same name in ColdFusion?

Tags: coldfusion

I'm generating several check boxes that all have the same name, when the form is processed I need to loop through the check boxes and get the ones that are checked for further processing. How would I do this using ColdFusion? Thanks!

Comment: What are you getting for the value of FORM.myCheckbox?

Comment: Well, if I have 2 check boxes checked I get the values returned like this "2,1". So I guess I can break that down as a list?

Comment: Yes, you want to treat it as a list. For example, cfloop can loop over a list.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<cfloop index="i" list="#FORM.supportSystems#"> 
    #i#
</cfloop>
```

Comment: Don't forget to use a CFPARAM. If none of the checkboxes are checked the variable won't exist in the FORM scope and you'll throw an error. `<cfparam name="form.supportSystems" default="" />`